# Handle different "domains" without subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, apache2

I have a server ("myserver") which only allows requests to the port 80 via HTTPS. Another limitation is that I cannot create subdomains, so I have to stick with "myserver".

Now, I have two applications: "frontend" running in port 8000 and "backend" in port 9000. Ideally, I would create two virtual hosts: "frontend.myserver" and "backend.myserver" using different document roots, server names, etc, but since it is not possible, I think I will have to work with paths such as "myserver/frontend" and "myserver/backend", for example.

Is it possible to do that? Do you know which configuration directive will allow me to do that? maybe using the alias directive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the subdomains with only a single IP address. In Apache, you will have to setup your virtual servers.

Check out the first example here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Notice that you setup each virtual server for each site you want to serve. Make sure you setup each of the following:

1. The listener for each virtual server as *:80
2. The DocumentRoot value pointing at your contect directories for each site
3. The ServerName value for each URL you want to serve

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /www/frontendcontent
   ServerName frontend.myserver
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /www/backendcontent
   ServerName backend.myserver
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

You may also need to use the ServerAlias directive if you want something like example.org and www.example.org to work. For that you would add ServerAlias just as you would the ServerName line, but specify the alias you want to work for that virtual server ServerName.
Here is the documentation on ServerAlias, but I suggest you get the above working, then work on the ServerAlias if necessary:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot have subdomains or different server names. I think it won't work this way, or it will?

Comment: I've updated my original reply above to include a sample apache config... It will work. The key is the ServerName variable. You must type the ServerName value into your web browser. Apache will look at the request being sent, and decide which virtual server to send the request depending on the site name that the web browser has requested.